# What does the statement "vector<int> myvector()" do? (confusion regarding parameterless constructor)

Tags: c++

I'm hoping someone can clear up my confusion, regarding the syntax where you try to use a parameterless constructor.  Now, I gather that the correct syntax is either without the parentheses:

```
foo myfoo;
vector<int> myvector;
```

Or alternatively, with the parentheses but like this:

```
foo myfoo = foo();
vector<int> myvector = vector<int>();
```

But then, the compiler does not complain about this form:

```
foo myfoo();
vector<int> myvector();
```

It does however then complain subsequently, when I attempt to reference a member of "myfoo" or "myvector":

```
myvector.push_back(1);  // "Error: expression must have class type"
```

So I gather from the above, that the form `someClass someInstance()` does not do what I expected (ie, instantiate the object using the parameterless constructor), but that it does do *something*.  So what exactly does it do?

Comment: `vector<int> myvector();` declares a function which returns type `vector<int>`

Comment: @billz: I think a more interesting question is *why* does it do that? When is that useful (i.e. when is that actually what you *want*)?

Comment: @Mehrdad, I like how the only answer for why is "because the standard says so".

Comment: @chris: So it's absolutely useless?

Comment: @Mehrdad, Definitely not in a place you'd expect a function declaration, but locally, I've never actually seen it used.

Comment: @Mehrdad used in `forward declaration` :)

Comment: @chris: I haven't seen it used either, but my question is *can* it even be used in the first place? When would you ever (forward?) declare a local function?

Comment: @billz: What? Can you give an example of when you would `forward-declare` something locally?

Comment: @Mehrdad The parsing rules should be different inside and outside of function scope?

Comment: @dyp: Yeah, why not? The language is already context-sensitive, might as well use that fact to make the programmer's life easier...

Comment: @billz of course ... thanks.  Obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'd find that confusing.. Well, nevertheless, you can *declare* a function with external linkage at block scope, see [basic.link]/6. This function then can be defined in another TU.

Comment: @dyp: Interesting, I didn't know that was possible. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mehrdad, I agree that it would be nice if it was different depending on scope. That opinion might be missing a crucial reason not to be, but the only thing I can think of is how you would declare a function locally if you *did* need to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a valid way to construct an object. If you attempt to call a no-arg constructor by typing:

```
MyType mytype();
```

The compiler interprets it as the declaration of a function called `mytype` that returns `MyType` and takes no arguments. Since the compiler thinks we're declaring a function, subsequent attempts to treat `mytype` as an object fail.

This referred to as the "Most Vexing Parse" because of its subtlety; you are far from the first person to fall victim to it.

As for why, I can only speculate, but here's some reasoning:

- Conceptually (meaning ignoring the standard and thinking about the structure of the syntax logically), the declaration is ambiguous. It's perfectly valid to declare a function like this, but its also perfectly valid for an object to have a no-arg constructor.
- The behavior should be consistent, e.g, regardless of whether this syntax is parsed as a function declaration or a constructor call, it should always be one and not the other.
- If parentheses are omitted, it is obvious that we are in fact creating an object, and the no-arg constructor will be called automatically. Therefore, an unambiguous syntax exists for a no-arg constructor call.
- There is no convenient way to declare a function without parentheses (technically it can be accomplished with `typedef`s, but come on? Do you really want a language where every no-arg function has to have its type declared inside a `typedef`?). Therefore, no such unambiguous syntax exists for a function declaration.
- Because of this, it makes sense to treat this syntax as a function declaration, as there is no other way to declare a function, while there is another way to create an object.

Again, pure speculation, but it makes sense to me.

Comment: +1. Pulled my hair out for the longest time because i was "calling" `glm::vec3 vert()`, and it was giving me undefined reference. At the time, I thought that all undefined reference meant was "you forgot to link something"

Comment: *"If parentheses are omitted, it is obvious that we are in fact creating an object, and the no-arg constructor will be called automatically. Therefore, an unambiguous syntax exists for a no-arg constructor call."* Unfortunately, it's not as simple as that. That's one reason for uniform initialization in C++11: `int x;` is uninitialized, but `int x{};` is value-initialized to `0`. Similarly for some kinds of classes (with no user-provided ctor etc.)

Comment: @dyp 1) see my edits. 2) If you don't provide a ctor, how would you expect your class to be initialized?

Comment: User-provided has a special meaning in C++11, a defaulted or deleted (default) constructor is not user-provided. Also, aggregates can be initialized via `struct my_aggregate { int x; double y; }; my_aggregate my_object = {4, 2.5};`